# List only the latest record when measure type and grade same

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my table structure.

```
Measure type       |Grade      |date  
LNF                |K          |1/1/2016
LNF                |K          |2/1/2016
CNF                |K          |3/1/2016
LDR                |K          |4/1/2016
```

LNF,CNF,LDR is measure types, K is grade level.
I need to list only the last record (by date) when measure type and grade level equal.

in the example correct query will list only the for LNF and Grade K.

```
LNF                |K          |2/1/2016
```

Total result must  be

```
LNF                |K          |2/1/2016
CNF                |K          |3/1/2016
LDR                |K          |4/1/2016
```

Please help me on this any my sql expert.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the condition for measure type and grade to be equals ?

Comment: Your edit has changed the request. However, NewUser gave a solution matching your new request an hour ago, and Giorgos Betsos gave a solution matching the original request (where you can remove the `HAVING` clause to get the same result) also an hour ago. Why don't you accept one of the answers? Is there still an issue unsolved?

Comment: Job done , Thank you very much Giorgos Betsos, New user, Thorsten Kettner for you commitment to this ticket . Great work falks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT Measuretype
    ,Grade
    ,Max(DATE) as LatestDate
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY Measuretype
    ,Grade
```

This would give output like this

```
Measure type       |Grade      |date  
LNF                |K          |2/1/2016
CNF                |K          |3/1/2016
LDR                |K          |4/1/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Measure type, Grade, MAX(date)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Measure type, Grade
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The query returns records having duplicate `Measure type, Grade` values. It selects the latest date for each group as requested in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, that was a bit confusing :-) You are looking for **duplicates** (two or more records with the same measure type and grade) and want to show the latest record per detected group.

```
select *
from mytable
where (measure_type, grade, date) in
(
  select measure_type, grade, max(date)
  from mytable
  group by measure_type, grade
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: The other answers are correct. As your table as shown only contains the grouped columns plus the date, you can simply select max(date) per group. You only need my query if your records contain more columns you want to show. As to your latest edit, where you want three rows rather than only the duplicate ones: remove `having count(*) > 1` from the query to achieve that.